# Why are values taken with get_var in wordpress not updated right away?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I created a kind of lighter social sharing plugin with a database integration to count clicks on social.

The clicks are counted correctly, but when I use this code:

```
$share = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT total_share FROM wp7n_social_share WHERE post_id = " . $id_post);
```

The value that comes back to me is the previous one. You have to close and reopen the page to see the updated value.

It is not a big problem, but I would like to understand why that string takes the previous value when in the db the value is already updated.

Thanks to whoever can answer me!

Comment: The title of the question doesn't make sense with the body of the question. There wasn't a mention to restricting access to pdf files if users aren't authenticated in the body of the question.

Comment: Thanks, I had confused the title with another question

Comment: The `$wpdb->get_var` method requires the values to be passed separately, not as part of the query string. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/

Comment: Can you explain better and do an example in a reply? Thanks